# How to configure ICUCollationField type in Solr 9?

Tags: solr, collation

I've tried to recreate Solr 8 configuration in Solr 9, but the following part in the config causes an error when creating core.

```
<fieldType name="text_gen_sort" class="solr.ICUCollationField" locale="" 
 numeric="true" strength="primary" multiValued="true" />
```

The following paths has been added in the `solrconfig.xml`:

```
<lib path="..../solr/modules/analysis-extras/lib/solr-analysis-extras-9.0.0.jar" />
<lib path="..../solr/modules/analysis-extras/lib/icu4j-68.2.jar" />
<lib path="..../solr/modules/analysis-extras/lib/lucene-analysis-icu-9.0.0.jar" />
```

and I checked, that the paths to jars are correct.

The stack trace is lengthy, here the relevant part of it:

```
<h3>Caused by:</h3><pre>java.lang.IllegalAccessError: 
class org.apache.solr.schema.ICUCollationField tried to access 
protected field org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.luceneVersion
(org.apache.solr.schema.ICUCollationField is in 
unnamed module of loader java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader @61639b88;
org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema is in unnamed module of loader
org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader @6a988392)
at org.apache.solr.schema.ICUCollationField.init(ICUCollationField.java:128)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.FieldType.setArgs(FieldType.java:202)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.FieldTypePluginLoader.init(FieldTypePluginLoader.java:149)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.FieldTypePluginLoader.init(FieldTypePluginLoader.java:43)
    at org.apache.solr.util.plugin.AbstractPluginLoader.load(AbstractPluginLoader.java:189)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.readSchema(IndexSchema.java:531)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.&lt;init&gt;(IndexSchema.java:188)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.ManagedIndexSchema.&lt;init&gt;(ManagedIndexSchema.java:119)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.ManagedIndexSchemaFactory.create(ManagedIndexSchemaFactory.java:279)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.ManagedIndexSchemaFactory.create(ManagedIndexSchemaFactory.java:51)
    at org.apache.solr.core.ConfigSetService.createIndexSchema(ConfigSetService.java:342)
    at org.apache.solr.core.ConfigSetService.lambda$loadConfigSet$0(ConfigSetService.java:253)
    at org.apache.solr.core.ConfigSet.&lt;init&gt;(ConfigSet.java:49)
    at org.apache.solr.core.ConfigSetService.loadConfigSet(ConfigSetService.java:249)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1550)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:1426)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminOperation.lambda$static$0(CoreAdminOperation.java:92)
```

Previous configuration with the same 3 libraries and the field type worked. I used `bin/solr create_core -c my_core -d my_configset`. The change is in the `managed-schema.xml`. (It used to be just `manages-schema` in Solr 8, but I recreated the configuration from the new default.)

Using  Private Build OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 13.0.7 13.0.7+5-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04 if that matters.

What can be the cause of this and how to overcome the problem?

Comment: I've also opened an issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-16219 as I suspect this is a bug.